How to acquire a redirection Url from GitHub OAuth app authentication in my SwiftUI app?
I am working on a project which strictly requires GitHub OAuth app authentication. I am redirecting the user from my app to GitHub using this link:
GET https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize
what I think should happen is for GitHub to ask for GitHub account of the user and then open my app using the redirection Url I give in the body of the first request. That is exactly what is happening but how can I get that redirection Url from GitHub because right now I am using AppDelegate but it is not being activated.
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel?

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        guard url.scheme == "my_scheme" else { return false }
    
        guard let code = getQueryStringParameter(url: url.absoluteString, param: "code"), let state = getQueryStringParameter(url: url.absoluteString, param: "state"), state == loginViewModel?.authService.state else { return false }
    
        Task {
            if let viewModel = loginViewModel {
                let success = await viewModel.authService.fetchAndStoreAccessToken(code: code)
    
                if success {
                    viewModel.loginState = .loggedIn
                } else {
                    viewModel.loginState = .loggedOut
                    print("Failed to fetch and store the access token.")
                }
            }
        }
    
        return true
    }

How to get it triggered?
I thought it is due to the dependancy of loginViewModel but after I debugged the whole program I uncovered that AppDelegate is never activated.

Try to look at ASWebAuthenticationSession. This is made for OAuth.
